# Setting up multiple document roots apache2 (server side (NOT local))

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am trying to set up two separate `DocumentRoot`s in my `httpd.conf`.

I have the following:

```
     NameVirtualHost 89.104.220.210
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/system.dk/html/
    ServerName  system.dk
    ErrorLog /logs/system
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 89.104.220.210>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/system.dk/html/system/
    ServerName  system.org
    ErrorLog /logs/system
    CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I attempt to restart, it fails to start:

```
    Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 89.104.220.207 for ServerName
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Can anyone help me out here?

**update**

I have the following now:

```
     NameVirtualHost 89.104.220.207:80
 NameVirtualHost 89.104.220.207:1500
#
# NOTE: NameVirtualHost cannot be used without a port specifier
# (e.g. :80) if mod_ssl is being used, due to the nature of the
# SSL protocol.
#

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known
# server name.
#
<VirtualHost 89.104.220.207:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/system.dk/html
     ServerName www.system.dk
     ServerAlias system.dk
     ErrorLog /var/www/learnbypower.dk/logs/error_log


</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 89.104.220.207:1500>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
     DocumentRoot /var/www/system/
     ServerName system
     ServerAlias system.dk
     ErrorLog /var/www/system.dk/logs/error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with below command on what error it does shows.

```
httpd -t
```

Also Apache Error logs when it fails. Default path is.

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```